# Is it possible to force ipengines to completely reset all local variables and imports?

Tags: ipython, ipython-parallel

My workflow is: start ipcontroller/ipengines, then run 'python test_script.py' several times with different parameters. This script includes a map_async call. The ipengines don't recognize changes to the code between calls to the script, and static class variables are not reset to their defaults. It seems like a magic %reset call would do the trick, but attempting to execute this command on the ipengines does not seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this was to use the ipengine to start a new subprocess which completes the desired operations. This subprocess has its own memory. Not ideal, but provides the desired functionality.